# How can I determine browser resolution in my mvc controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, screen-resolution

I know that I can use Javascript to get the browser's resolution but I can't figure out how to get it back to the controller so that I can calculate grid row and column sizes. I am not allowed to use scrollbars, I have to have the grid show exactly what will fit for that page.

Comment: this should be done with css and/or javascript. There's no need to send the dimensions back to the controller

Comment: Let's just assume that I do need to, is it possible or does it break the pattern? FYI - I am dynamically changing the data stream and injecting cells based on screen size to account for widows/orphans and group titles.

Comment: what happens when I change the window size? You'll have to get the value in JS then either ajax or post the the dimensions to update the table. I still think a [responsive](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive) design is the better option

Answer (score 3):

You could use [51degrees.mobi](http://51degrees.mobi/Support/Documentation/Foundation.aspx), but it's not free for what you need.

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       int x = Request.Browser.ScreenPixelsWidth;
       int y = Request.Browser.ScreenPixelsHeight;
   }
```

Comment: My answers for this technique were incorrect on my testing.